# GAE datastore: Entity deleted only after multiple calls to delete()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

I'm playing with the GAE datastore on a local machine with Eclipse. I've created two servlets - `AddMovie` and `DeleteMovie`:

#### AddMovie

```
Entity movie = new Entity("movie",System.currentTimeMillis());
movie.setProperty("name",     "Hakeshset Beanan");
movie.setProperty("director", "Godard");
datastore.put(movie);
```

#### DeleteMovie

```
Query q = new Query("movie");
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
List<Entity> movies = Lists.newArrayList(pq.asIterable());
response.put("numMoviesFound", String.valueOf(movies.size()));

for (Entity movie : movies) {
    Key key = movie.getKey();
    datastore.delete(key);
}
```

The funny thing is that the DeleteMovie servlet does not delete all the movies. Consecutive calls return `{"numMoviesFound":"15"}`, then `{"numMoviesFound":"9"}`, `{"numMoviesFound":"3"}` and finally `{"numMoviesFound":"3"}`.

**Why aren't all movies deleted from the datastore at once?**

**Update:** The problem seem to happen only on the local Eclipse, not on GAE servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should delete all your movies in a single transaction, it would ensure better consistency.

Talking about consistency, your problem is right here :

> Google App Engine's High Replication Datastore (HRD) provides high availability for your reads and writes by storing data synchronously in multiple data centers. However, the delay from the time a write is committed until it becomes visible in all data centers means that queries across multiple entity groups (non-ancestor queries) can only guarantee eventually consistent results. Consequently, the results of such queries may sometimes fail to reflect recent changes to the underlying data.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency